# How can I become the Hero of Caldeum?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I've tried this segment two or three times now, with and without allies.  I can't seem to save enough of the peasants to get this achievement.

If I stop long enough to kill off the enemies, they all seem to decide the best place to stand is in the shadow of one of Belial's meteors.  If I just run like crazy, the monsters eat them for lunch.  If I take my time, I either run out of time or get to the peasants just as they're becoming lunch and/or a bloody smear on the bazaar walls.

What's the trick to saving enough of the peasants to get this achievement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### General Concept

**The "trick" is not having them die and choosing to take more efficient paths to this end so as to also collect enough refugees and not run out of time**. This involves protecting them from the constantly spawning enemies and the randomly placed meteors. Having sufficient crowd control through abilities and monions/followers is really the only way to keep the enemies at bay. Movement speed bonuses are useful if you need to run back and help out as well as get to the refugees faster, but the refugees don't go faster because of this. As far as the meteors are concerned, you just have to keep your eye out and back off if you don't think the refugees will make it past an oncoming meteor. As far as time, try to get reasonably-sized groups of refugees together in each trip in order to take fewer trips.

I've completed the requirements for this achievement several times with each class on single player. Witch Doctor is by far the easiest class to earn this achievement with. All of the followers work very well so take whichever you like best, but I prefer Scoundrel's speed and crowd control and Templar's aggro gain and crowd control. Crowd control abilities that stop/slow/distract enemies can be useful here as can abilities that increase movement speed. Any of the class' minion summoning spells are great for distracting the enemies, especially if the minions can be targeted by enemy attacks (monk and witch doctor).

The AI pathing for the refugees is pretty bad and they sometimes wander or run off to the middle of nowhere (or to try and fight the enemies?) and that's often your worst enemy. Learning when/where the enemies spawn is helpful as the worrisome spawns are always the same and triggered by your actions so you can learn where to attack. The meteors are your second biggest worry as they seem completely random.

### My Strategy

I'm sure there are better strategies, but the approach that I took to consistently complete this achievement with each of the classes involved 4 trips and was as follows:

[image: Hero of Caldeum paths]

I added the unmarked refugees and drew out the paths in the above image.

1. While Asheara is still talking about the Iron Wolves saving people, get near **the cart nearest to the sewer entrance (a bit north-west)**. If there's a meteor coming, let her talk, but once it hits, skip the speech and push the cart. You should be close enough to the sewer that he should very easily path to the escape. This is 1 refugee and should take like 5-10 seconds at most. At the very start, there are also 2 more refugees in the center of the beginning chaos in the middle of the right side of the bazaar and they tend to die very quickly from the enemies that spawn there and the frequent meteors, but if you are lucky and your minions, skills or the Iron Wolves protect them sufficiently, you can grab these 2 as well for a total of 3 refugees in about 15-20 seconds.
2. Run diagonally north-east through the chaos to **the stalls and cart towards the top-center of the of the bazaar**. Quickly push the cart and hang a bit to the north if there's a meteor so the citizen crawling out doesn't walk right into it, move to the left of the stall to make another crawl out and, including the fellow already standing there, you should have 3 with you at this point. Here's the first tricky bit. An enemy will spawn right in the middle of these stalls so attack as it spawns to kill it quickly. Run south through the chaos directly to the sewer, avoiding the meteors (If they mark the spot you are on, you should be OK to continue as long as nothing distracts the refugees. If you need, you could try hooking around the left where the first citizen was, but I've not had much luck that way, By this point you should have 4-6 and that last bit shouldn't have taken more than 20-30 seconds.
3. Run **to the east, near the entrance to the bazaar** to hit the cart just south-east of that archway. An enemy will spawn south of there while another will come up behind you - dispatch them. Next  hit the cart north of the arch and continue north, dispatching the enemy that spawns there, to pick up the two along the way. Continue all the way to the north-east to grab the group of 3 up there. Head south, passing the north side of the fountain and another will crawl out. 1 or 2 enemies should spawn in your way and the meteors get annoying at this point. You will be guiding 8 refugees and the AI pathing can be uncooperative so this is the challenging run, following the same return path used in 2. You should have saved up to 11-14 by this point and this bit takes close to 1 minute.
4. Quickly, run **west through the gate to the other end of the bazaar** and a refugee may join you on the way (if not, he'll catch up on the return trip). Hit the cart to the north and then the one to the south. An enemy will spawn to your left - kill it. Continue south of the fountain to hit the north and then south carts there. Another enemy will spawn - it can die. Collect the group of 3 just north of here and hit the other cart for one more. Another will crawl out of a cart on the left At this point, you should have enough, but if you don't, there are 2 more in the stalls to the north. Dallying here can cost you though as it allows more enemies to spawn. When done here, return to the sewer for your reward. You can collect up to 12 more here and this should take 1 minute or so. The enemies in this run seem to spawn along your path rather than behind so they're easier to take out before they cause trouble.

There are a total of 26 refugees and you need to rescue 20 of them so you can let at most 6 die or not even grab them if you like. This should take about 2:40 at most of the 3:00 so you should have some leeway on the time. You could probably tag trip 2 on the end of trip 3 and save a trip, but with the enemy spawn frequency and locations as well as the argumentative AI, I found the refugees pathed better and died less when there were fewer of them for trip 3.

Comment: This ach seems to be bugged for me.  I've done it lots of times, and I count and I usually get 22+ refugees, but i'm never rewarded the achievement.  I think I got it on the first day, and they lost it, and the recent ach fix didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, movespeed is vital. im a WW barb so i sprint constantly, also contadictory to an above poster the villiagers WILL pick up the pace to keep up with your increased movespeed. quickly sweep around the first "area", picking up villagers as fast as possible, sprinting/vaulting/whatever movespeed increases u can fathom with ur given class, returning them in groups of none less then say 5-10. it should take you 20-30 secs to clear ALL the villiagers, tadaa easy achieve :)

ps if u find ur villagers standing in stupid places or are surrounded by enemies, dont just stand there or try to kill them unless u can take im in 1-2 shots. if not, run like crazy with whatever movespeed skill u may have, they will follow.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with this in singleplayer too. If you have someone to coop with try it because it seems that the frequency of meteors is divided by the two players.

If you want to do it on your own try to use your best singletarget ability to snipe the enemies and run snakelines to avoid the meteors. There is no trick for this achievement, maybe you are just terribly unlucky but if you wait for meteors to come down and then sprint through you should be getting enough peasants into safety.

Answer (score 0):

I had no trouble with the meteors when I did it, they seem to fall in fairly specific spots and since there is a marker for when they'll fall you can tell when it is safe to walk or not. Aside from that I mostly just ignored the mobs and ran the peasants to the sewer. The guards would take care of any that followed, if they were really in my way I could usually kill them in 1-2 hits.