# What's the point in doing scouring of caldeum?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do we get cash or goods if we save citizens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every citizen you save drops an amount of gold equivalent to what a white mob in the current act/area/difficulty would drop, complete with the randomness that entails. Sometimes you can get thousands of gold for saving just a few citizens.

You also get a small exp bonus at the end of the quest depending on how many you saved.

Comment: ...and on top of that, if you save 20 or more civilians, you get an achievement. Wowzers!

Comment: Not worth saving !... Die citizen die.... Now I see how politicians think of us :D

Comment: If anyone wants help getting the achievement, look [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70396/how-can-i-become-the-hero-of-caldeum).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed also; that completing this event on A2 Inferno anyway, that there's a chest if you follow the civilians into the sewer after the event is over.  I'm unsure if the chest is random, or if the # of people saved determines the quality (I definitely didn't save them all), but I honestly haven't even checked up until this last playthrough.

Comment: It follows regular chest rules.